# Dielectric Problem Boundary Condition

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, boundary-conditions

I am given two concentric conductive spherical shells, one of radius $a$, and the other of radius $b$, with $b>a$. The space between these shells is filled with a dielectric of relative permittivity $\kappa$. The inner shell has a charge of $+q$ and the outer shell is **grounded**.

I would like to solve for the potential within the dielectric medium as a function of $r$, and use it to compute the surface charge density on the outer plate.

Considering Laplace Equation in Spherical Coordinates, the solution takes the form:
$$V(r,\theta)=\sum_{l=0}^{\infty}{\bigg(A_l+\frac{B_l}{r^{l+1}}}\bigg)P_l(\cos\theta)$$

By spherical symmetry, we know that there exists no dependence on $\theta$, thus we need only to consider the first term in the summation:
$$V(r)=A+\frac{B}{r}$$
We will need boundary conditions to determine $A$ and $B$. Consider the surface charge density on the inner plate:
$$\sigma=\frac{+q}{4\pi a^2}$$
This surface charge is associated with a discontinuity of the Electric Field at $r=a$. Using Gauss Law considered in the vicinity of a surface charge:
$$-\sigma=\epsilon_{above}\frac{\partial V_{above}}{\partial r}-\epsilon_{below}\frac{\partial V_{below}}{\partial r}\Biggr|_{r=a}$$
Since the shell is conductive, it is an equipotential i.e. $V_{below} = constant$. Thus the above formula reduces to:
$$-\sigma=\kappa \epsilon_0 \frac{\partial V_{above}}{\partial r}\Biggr|_{r=a}$$
Substituting $\sigma$ and $\partial_r V_{above}$ we obtain:
$$\frac{-q}{4\pi a^2}=\kappa \epsilon_0 \frac{-B}{a^2}$$
Simplifying:
$$B=\frac{q}{4\pi \kappa \epsilon_0}$$
Applying the second boundary condition of the grounded potential $V(b)=0$:
$$0=A+\frac{B}{b}$$
Rearranging and subsituting:
$$A=\frac{-B}{b}=\frac{-q}{4\pi \kappa \epsilon_0 b}$$
Thus the potential in the bulk of the dielectric is given by:
$$V(r)=\frac{q}{4\pi \kappa \epsilon_0}\biggr(\frac{1}{r}-\frac{1}{b}\biggr),\quad a < r < b$$
To compute the surface charge density at the outer shell, we need to consider the potential outside the outer shell $r>b$. We will repeat the process outside the shell.

Following a similar argument:
$$V(r)=C+\frac{D}{r}$$
We have the boundary condition $V(b)=0$ thus:
$$C+\frac{D}{b}=0$$
But we are **missing a boundary condition**...and now I'm stuck. We should probably get $C=D=0$, but I cannot justify it. Could someone justify it for me with another boundary condition, and some physical justification for it.

EDIT: I know that this is an overkill technique for a simple problem, the answer is $-q/{4\pi b^2}$ but I am trying to solve it as a boundary value problem for practice.

Comment: ...why the close vote? This isn't a homework question, I already know the answer.

Comment: You can use Gauss law, picking a sphere that encloses both conductors as integration surface.

Comment: It doesn't have to be literally homework, hence the HW&E tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the "trivial" boundary condition $V \rightarrow0$ as $r\rightarrow\infty$ for a charge distribution spread over a finite volume/area/length.

$\therefore \hspace{2pt} V(\infty)=C=0 $ by using your first condition $0+\frac{D}{b}=0$ gives $D=0$.

Surface charge density of grounded shell
$$-\sigma=\epsilon_{above}\frac{\partial V_{above}}{\partial r}\Biggr|_{r=b^+}-\epsilon_{below}\frac{\partial V_{below}}{\partial r}\Biggr|_{r=b^-}$$
$$\implies-\sigma=0-\kappa\epsilon_0\frac{q}{4\pi \kappa \epsilon_0}\bigg(-\frac{1}{b^2}\bigg)$$
$$\implies\sigma=-\frac{q}{4\pi b^2}$$

Comment: My problem is, how can I ensure that $V(\infty)=0$, you see we set the reference potential arbitrarily, how can I be sure that our choice of the shell $r=b$ at zero potential is consistent with $V$ vanishing at $r\rightarrow \infty$, and not some other constant?

Comment: You can use the arguments in [here](http://web.mit.edu/6.013_book/www/chapter5/5.2.html#:~:text=If%20there%20is%20no%20charge,of%20solutions%20to%20Laplace's%20equation.&text=The%20presumably%20different%20solutions%20a,satisfy%20the%20same%20boundary%20conditions.) to feel confident about this solution.